# Cannot access Pepper applications

Tags: application-server, pepper

We have received a new Pepper robot about 4 weeks ago. The robot uses the Python SDK to NAOqi 2.5.10.7. We are able to work with the Python API functions, program our dialogues and new behaviors, but we cannot access most of the applications in the Aldebaran Cloud. At https://cloud.aldebaran-robotics.com/application/ there are (after Sign in) only 16 applications listed, most of which are either already contained in the Basic channel or they are incompatible with Pepper (Grasping, Move Recorder, ...) even with the filter Pepper selected at the top.

[image: applications panel]
<sub>(source: [hales at charon.fi.muni.cz](http://charon.fi.muni.cz/~hales/pepper/applications.png))</sub>

Moreover, a number of these (and others, mentioned elsewhere in the documentation or on the web) are not accessible - when going to their URL, the page redirects to the main cloud page `:-(` E.g.

- https://cloud.aldebaran-robotics.com/application/come-here/
- https://cloud.aldebaran-robotics.com/application/explore-c8782b/
- https://cloud.aldebaran-robotics.com/application/exploration-manager/

These even include the applications already installed on the robot - there are 47 packages currently installed (seen in the Manage robot page), so most of them are not accessible at the web. Some of the installed applications were added by Aldebaran support, who evidently can access them (e.g. https://cloud.aldebaran-robotics.com/application/autonomous-recharge/), but we cannot.

We have already asked the support about this (several times), but they did not come with any solution.

Is this caused by some error with our account settings?